# Which datasets-merging operation would do this in Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, join, merge

Lets say I have two pandas DataFrames, X and Y:

```
X =
+---+----------+---------+
|   | Value1   | Value2  |
+---+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |   NaN   |
| B |    0     |    0    |
+---+----------+---------+

Y =
+---+----------+---------+
|   | Value1   | Value2  |
+---+----------+---------+
| A |    2     |   NaN   |
| C |    30    |   NaN   |
+---+----------+---------+
```

I want to merge / join them based on the index (row name) resulting in this:

```
+---+----------+---------+
|   | Value1   | Value2  |
+---+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |    2    |
| B |    0     |    0    |
| C |    30    |   NaN   |
+---+----------+---------+
```

Using merge and 'outer', the resulting table has columns per table, instead of just concatenating. I need something that appends new rows to the end, but also appends new columns for a matching index.

This is the result of an 'outer' merge:

```
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|   | Value1_X | Value2_X| Value1_Y | Value2_Y|
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |   NaN   |    2     |   NaN   |
| B |    0     |    0    |   NaN    |   NaN   |
| C |   NaN    |   NaN   |    30    |   NaN   |
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Which is almost what I want, but ignoring the original column labels...

Comment: Append Y to X and then drop duplicates.

Comment: that would leave me with two rows with index A, one with value 1, and another with value 2, right?

Comment: Okay. I see your problem now. So, tell me, what if in X: index A had value 1, 1. How should the output be in that case?

Comment: And yes, that would leave you with two rows, with value 1 and 2. You can get your desired output from that by making a grouping but there are some edge cases, like the one I asked above.

Comment: I would like it to just add a new column for each new value. If X had A,1,1 , then the result would be A,1,1,2 ... the issue is I am not respecting the column names and want to dynamically append columns. This could be done using arrays or dictionaries, but I thought maybe there is a way using database operations in Pandas

Comment: Just a final question. That 2 is in which column? Column 'Value1' or 'Value2'?

Comment: that would be 'Value1_Y', or could be even 'Value 3'. I think I see the issue with this better now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the result of the 'outer' merge:

```
X = 
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|   | Value1_X | Value2_X| Value1_Y | Value2_Y|
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |   NaN   |    2     |   NaN   |
| B |    0     |    0    |   NaN    |   NaN   |
| C |   NaN    |   NaN   |    30    |   NaN   |
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

do, `X = X.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis = 1)`

which will give

```
    0     1
A   1.0   2.0
B   0.0   0.0
C   30.0  NaN
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think the third row also ends up with a 0.0 instead of a NaN